# app crashes when criteria set to high accuracy

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am trying to get the highest possible location accuracy, which I have learned is from GPS provider. I only need to get the location once, so I am not concerned about the effect on battery life. In my code, which is functional, the location seems to alternate between totally inaccurate (1+km) to very accurate (within 10m). Throughout the testing of my app, I am enabling/disabling location on my phone, turning on/off wifi, turning on/off data. This is just to experiment and see how each affects the accuracy and the app in general.

The following code is my onCreate method from the location activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);

    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment))
            .getMap();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    //criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(2 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
}
```

My app crashes however when I add the `criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);` line.

What is going on?

**EDIT: this is the logcat error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.locationget, PID: 16663    
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.locationget/com.locationget.MapActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: accuracy=3    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)     
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)    
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: accuracy=3    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.location.Criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.java:223)    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.getlocation.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:47)    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271    
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)     
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)        
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)        
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)        
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)        
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)     
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)     
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)       
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)     
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm relatively new to android, not really sure what is the relevant part.

Comment: show us the stack trace of the error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line is the real error:

`E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.locationget/com.locationget.MapActivity}:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: accuracy=3`

This is what I found after some searchs:

> The android Criteria has two separate groups of accuracy constants.
>   ACCURACY_FINE and ACCURACY_COARSE are for general location, while
>   ACCURACY_LOW, ACCURACY_MEDIUM, and ACCURACY_HIGH "may be used for
>   horizontal, altitude, speed or bearing accuracy."

So in your case, don't use `ACCURACY_HIGH` or you'll get an error. Use `ACCURACY_COARSE` or `ACCURACY_FINE` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use `criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);` 
instead of `criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);`.

[Criteria](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html)